# Cannot access https service from localhost WampServer64

Tags: wampserver

I am using WampServer64 for web development and I have been having an issue with not being able to access web services, namely my own, using https. The same services will work when accessed via http and in production environments on a web server, those same web services are being accessed via https all the time, so the https does work.

For example, on the localhost, I can't access data from https://mytestservice.com/a-service, but it will work no problem if I do http://mytestservice.com/a-service. Is there any way around this? I haven't really seen any instructions on how to make this work, the closest I have seen to that would be to install a dummy ssl on Wamp, which I have already done.

Comment: Is the `php_openssl` extension enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled.

Comment: Have you defined a Virtual Host for your HTTPS access?